# react-native build in ios is failing

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening appChat.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the appChat editor. (in target 'appChat' from project 'appChat')
PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'appChat' from project 'appChat')
cd /Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/appChat/ios
/bin/sh -c /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh

Ld /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.app/appChat normal x86_64 (in target 'appChat' from project 'appChat')
cd /Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/appChat/ios
/Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -isysroot /Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Glog -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-PeerTalk -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-RSocket -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlipperKit -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTTypeSafety -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -L/Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/appChat/ios/Pods/CocoaLibEvent/lib -L/Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/appChat/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib -F/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/appChat.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/appChat_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lCocoaAsyncSocket -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFlipper -lFlipper-DoubleConversion -lFlipper-Folly -lFlipper-Glog -lFlipper-PeerTalk -lFlipper-RSocket -lFlipperKit -lFolly -lRCTTypeSafety -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lYoga -lYogaKit -lcrypto -levent -levent_core -levent_extra -levent_pthreads -lglog -lssl -lstdc++ -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework UIKit -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.build/appChat.app-Simulated.xcent -lPods-appChat -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appChat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/appChat_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.app/appChat
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:
_RAND_poll in libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'OpenSSL-Universal' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/appChat/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/appChat/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/appChat/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appChat-harahrtedyippagwwsabailtrlap/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appChat.app/appChat normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Comment: have you tried cleaning your build, pod install, and then run the app again?

Comment: yes i tried but still i got the same error

Comment: did you find the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

just go to x-code open your project there is a folder of pods click on that
after that Pods -> React-codegen -> Deployment -> ios Deployment target
on this select the ios version 13